# Browser Detection and Compatibility Checking with Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, compatibility, browser-detection

I am trying to detect browser types and IE compatibility from user agent and redirect accordingly. It works only in IE but not in Firefox and Chrome. I am still looking around the solution and cannot figure out yet.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing </title>
<script src="UserAgent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results">Output</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

if (UserAgent.firefox){
    window.location.href("http://www.yahoo.com");
}

if (UserAgent.compatibilityMode) {
    window.location.href("http://192.168.10.236/iecorrect.html");
} else {
    window.location.href("http://www.apple.com");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UserAgent.js

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
document.write("\<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'>\<\/script>");
}

// Create new object
var UserAgent = {
init: function () {
    // Get the user agent string
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    this.compatibilityMode = false;      
    this.firefox = ua.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1;
    this.chrome = ua.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") > -1

    if (ua.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") > -1) {
        this.compatibilityMode = true;
    }
}
};

// Initialize the object
ieUserAgent.init();
```

Comment: What do you need this for?? For visualizing a warning to the user, like "Upgrade to a more decent browser" or for something else??

Comment: Our site is actually put in compatibility mode in several client IE, so redirect them to the instruction page to remove from compatibility view setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your window.loacation.href calls to the below code:

```
if (UserAgent.compatibilityMode) {
    window.location.href = "http://192.168.10.236/iecorrect.html";
} else {
    window.location.href = "http://www.apple.com";
}
```

You wrote them like you would write jQuery :)

Comment: Also, you can use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to force IE user out of compatibility mode.

Comment: Not a problem! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To check for IE and/or a specific version of IE you are better off using conditional statements.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: I don't actually want to know IE version. I just want to know Compatibility view status. The main problem is the main html cannot redirect for firefox or chrome.

Comment: Have you tried adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> to prevent compatibility mode?